# FatFree framework MVC

Tags: php, mvc, framework, fat-free

Суть:

Входной скрипт:

```
$f3=require('lib/base.php');
$f3->config('config/config.ini');
$f3->config('config/routes.ini');
$f3->run();
```

Код контроллера:

```
class Controller {
    protected $f3;
    protected $db;
    function beforeroute() {
    }
    function afterroute() {
        $view = new View;
        echo $view->render('layout.html');
    }
    function __construct() {
        $f3=Base::instance();
        $db=new DB\SQL(
            $f3->get('db_dns') . $f3->get('db_name'),
            $f3->get('db_user'),
            $f3->get('db_pass')
        );
        $this->f3=$f3;
        $this->db=$db;
    }
}
```

И файл шаблона:

```
include('header.html');
include('error.html');
include($view);
include('footer.html');
```

Фреймворк, это только $view. В файле header.html имеется меню, которое нужно сделать динамическим, в зависимости от некоторых данных в бд, некоторые пункты меню должны выводиться непосредственно из бд, но оно находится вне контроллера и я не знаю что с этим делать.

Я могу - записать в сессию(массив не запишешь) и создать глобальную переменную, но данные из бд для меню придется доставать в абсолютно всех контроллерах, что не есть хорошо. Как поступить?

Comment: Здесь вот предложен метод через наследование от Layout
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021759/fat-free-php-layouts][1]

Answer (score 1):

Можно определить все данные которые относятся к меню в каждом контроллере. Либо переназначить стандартный контроллер, добавить что-то новое для меню. Так-же можно сделать либку чтобы работала с меню и вызвать её в самом шаблоне или контроллере с непосредственной передачей в шаблон.